# pipe command to mailx and do not send mail if no content

Tags: bash, pipe, mailx

I have a system (rhel5) that does not support `mailx`'s `-E` option (for not sending email if the body is empty). Is there a one liner that i could use to simulate this feature? eg the first would send, but the second wouldn't

```
echo 'hello there' | blah | mailx -s 'test email' me@you.com
echo '' | blah | mailx -s 'test email' me@you.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. "one-liner" is sort of relative, since these are technically one-liners but they may not suit you:

```
stuff=$(echo 'hello there') ; [ -n "${stuff}" ] && echo ${stuff} | mailx -s 'test email' me@you.com
stuff=$(echo '') ; [ -n "${stuff}" ] && echo ${stuff} | mailx -s 'test email' me@you.com
```

Comment: hehe, yeah... i know what you mean. i had something similar but i was thinking that there was some bash built-in that could terminate the pipe upon some condition.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely is your real question. [This question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976139/shell-pipe-exit-immediately-when-one-command-fails) seems to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with a trick rather than a program to pipe to:

```
msg='hello there' && [ -n "$msg" ] && echo "$msg" | mailx -s 'test email' me@you.com
```

If your message comes from another script you would have to run it as

```
msg="$(get_it)" && [ -n "$msg" ] && echo "$msg" | mailx -s 'test email' me@you.com
```

If `[ ... ]` is not supported you can also use `[[ ... ]]`:

```
msg="$(get_it)" && [[ -n "$msg" ]] && echo "$msg" | mailx -s 'test email' me@you.com
```